# javascript: how to make multiple combo boxes with same data

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i have a scenario in JSP where i have to make a combo with a list containing 10 items say 1,2,3.... 10. now i select a combo. I also need to provide an add button that will add another combo with same elements except the one being selected in previous combo.

eg- if 1st combo selected value is 1 then in the next combo i'll have the list as 2,3,4.....10 i.e, having 9 elements and so on. the user can add 10 combos like this, each combo having the items that haven't been previously selected.

can anyone help me with this???
thanks in advance :) !!!

Comment: If you are using struts then try using `<s:combo box ../>` ?

Answer (score 0):

just to clear things out, your scenario is that you have 10 combo boxes that contain values from 1 to 10... i suggest you can use a case statement, or multiple if statements, you can use javascript for that...

Comment: suppose i select the 1st combo with value 10. then i click on add button and it creates another combo having items 1,2,3,4.....9 but not 10 as its already selected in previous combo.
and if i select 1 in second combo then after clicking on add button a combo will appear having same items but not 10 and 1 coz they have already been selected. this is what i want.

Comment: you will be having different arrays such as {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and the others, and each array has 1 missing number between 1 to 10, and your if statement will go like 
    x=10;
    if (combobox.value == 1) 
    {
    while (x!=1)
    selectBox.options.add(x);
    x--;
    }
the logic of the code will look somewhat like this...